# conda fails to create environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

How can I fix the following problem in conda where it fails to create a new environment?

```
conda create --name snowflakes biopython                                                                      130 ↵
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/geoheil/.conda/envs/snowflakes:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    biopython:  1.68-np112py36_0
    mkl:        2017.0.1-0      
    numpy:      1.12.0-py36_0   
    openssl:    1.0.2k-1        
    pip:        9.0.1-py36_1    
    python:     3.6.0-0         
    readline:   6.2-2           
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py36_0   
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0        
    tk:         8.5.18-0        
    wheel:      0.29.0-py36_0   
    xz:         5.2.2-1         
    zlib:       1.2.8-3         

Proceed ([y]/n)? y 

mkl-2017.0.1-0 100% |######################################################################| Time: 0:00:14   9.39 MB/s
numpy-1.12.0-p 100% |######################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   9.51 MB/s
biopython-1.68 100% |######################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   9.26 MB/s
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(330): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::readline-6.2-2'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. /opt/anaconda/pkgs/readline-6.2-2/lib/libhistory.a

Attempting to roll back.



CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. /opt/anaconda/pkgs/readline-6.2-2/lib/libhistory.a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like somehow your package cache directory got corrupted. It is not a fault with the package upstream, because https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/readline-6.2-2.tar.bz2 definitely contains that file. Try:

```
conda env remove -yn snowflakes
conda remove readline -y --force
conda clean --all -y
conda install readline -y
conda create -n snowflakes biopython
```

Comment: I can't execute remove readline due to `would require removing conda dependnecies`

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Use `--force` to remove the package without removing dependencies.

Comment: That is just shifting the issue to the next thing conda create -n snowflakes biopython I assume clean --all deleted all the packages, how can I reinstall all packages now? Maybe the new environment can be created then.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler `clean --all` will only clean the cache.

Comment: So when I now get `CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. /opt/anaconda/pkgs/sqlite-3.13.0-0/lib/libsqlite3.a` as the issue, I need to assume there are problems with all packages. How could I remove and reinstall all the packages?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can `rm -fr /opt/anaconda/pkgs/` and setup conda again, by doing: bash `/path/to/install -b -f -p /opt/anaconda`